# how to set if a value of variable is null, then wait. i am using angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

How to setup code that, if variable value is null below LOC will not execute,

EXA:-

```
int A=Waiting for value from diff controller
```

//wait until getting response of above variable,Then

```
{LOC}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `wait` ? Do you mean an asynchronous call needs to be made to set the `LOC` variable ? Can you post more of your code so we can understand the context ? 

Basically, to help you toward the right direction, you need to use either `Observables` or `Promises` to wait for your variable to be set. You can link that to a single `if(LOC)` that will check if your variable is defined and not null.

Comment: LOC=line of code, i know that var value will change but it depend on user click and it's value change after that(The User click is set to other component)

Comment: Okay, so your solution could be to use a shared service that will manage the state of your user click (like a `toggle` / `collapse` state). From your different components, you will be able to access this service with dependency injection, and from one component set the service state, while the other one will look and react on the service state to trigger an action. This is most probably what you are looking for

Comment: Yeh Exactly, How To achive it, while the other one will look and react on the service state to trigger an action, Any Code Paste On Answer, Or Link

Answer (score 1):

You can write conditional expression binding

```
public appLoaded = null;

{{appLoaded ? "App is loaded" : "Wait"}}
```